# Struggling with this.props in nested components

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

Apologies if this is a basic question but I am new to react/gatsby and i am struggling to find an answer to my question as i am not sure the exact terminology.

I am currently building a site using atomic design principles. i want to update the copy for atom components such as buttons/forms when they are used around the site - however i am struggling to pass data using the methods i know of.

---

### Code set up

**Atom/Button components** the text is coded as such
`<button>{this.props.copy}</button>`

**Layout component such as a hero banner** The button is imported in the layout using 
`<section>This is a hero banner <button copy="copy goes here" /></section>`

**Page component** I want to use the layout/hero component across various pages, I've imported the layout component and overwrite the button text already defined in the layout component however using 
`<layout copy="overwrite the copy">` 
obviously will not work

---

Is there a way to either pull a component into another component as it is called in such as `<hero <button copy="new copy"/> />`  and overwrite the prop. OR a better way to define props in the atom components that they can be nested. so the structure looks like this (the third level components are always in layouts and rarely pulled into the page by themselves.)

Page 1 
Page 2 
├── Layout (Hero)
├─────── Atom (button)
├─────── Atom (Input)
└─────── Atom (Select)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the component to a variable? And the pass the var as prop?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here:

1. `Prop Drilling`
2. `Render Props` ([React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)).

I am going to say avoid Prop Drilling as much as possible. It becomes cumbersome on large component hierarchies. Try a more dynamic approach with the render props that allows you swap out implementations with out causing issues.

**Prop Drilling:**

This would involve passing props down the component hierarchy. For your use case, it would look like this

```
class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                This is a hero banner <AtomButton copy={this.props.copy} /> 
            </section>
        )
    }
}

class AtomButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button>this.props.copy</button>
        )
    }
}
```

**Render Props:**

What I am showing here is not actually a render prop. This is just passing a component down as a prop and then rednering the component. A true render props is defined in the React docs I linked.

```
class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section> This is a hero banner {this.props.button} /><section>
        )
    }
}

//Wherever your are loading your Layout Component
class Page extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout buttonRender={<AtomButton copy="overwrite copy" />} />              
        )
    }
}
```